# How can i create result/report of Execution of tests in Java

Tags: java, swing, selenium

I have created a runner and error handler for my selenium tests. I am able to store the errors in `String Builder` and after execution i Print it on Console.

I want to create HTML report from the execution.

How can i achieve it. Should I store all things in Variable if yes how for each test. Should I Write in some format and the write some filter for the same.

Please let me know how to do this.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You should integrate it into JUnit (or equivalent framework). Then you get access to lots of reporting tools.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created on class name result and it has some variables and function using this I can create result in HTML format with css and also get an xml log file.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Most people use [JUnit](http://www.junit.org) and/or [JBehave](http://jbehave.org/) to drive their Selenium tests, which comes with html reporting built-in.

Fully fledged example from the JBehave website is available here: http://jbehave.org/reference/web/stable/using-selenium.html

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not using any default runners i have created my own framework but i am not able to create reports. I don't want to use runners available like junit, testng etc. Do u have any idea about creating the report by code. Fail must show error what occurred and where occurred.

Comment: "I don't want to use runners available like junit, testng etc". Why not?

Comment: @Thilo: I have created it as per requirements of client and it should work in different way and this is not available in existing runners.

Answer (score 0):

A simply way I suggest is to append all the printout statements in a storage variable like string buffer(Java) with delimiters like | symbols at the end of each line and then write this information into a text file.(line by line by split with the help of | symbols)

If you want to store this information in excel you will have to use the Apache POI Project to write data into excel sheets.(http://poi.apache.org/)